# Docker container log does not appear anymore on Docker compose log

Tags: docker, docker-compose, restart, docker-container

I'm running my Docker container through my Docker compose, but when my container stops and it restarts again, the log does not appear anymore related to this restarted container.

Would anyone know how to fix it?

I send below the docker compose command and the file for analysis.

Thank you in advance.

**Command to start the compose**

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up
```

**Docker compose**

```
version: '3'

services:
  ms3_executive_back:
    image: ms3_executive_backend
    ports:
     - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
     - ./executive_backend:/app
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inspect the logs to determine cause of failure, you can try setting your `restart: "no"`. This will ensure that docker-compose does not automatically restart your container and overwrite the existing logs.